# .htaccess - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect user based on their user agent to a specific websites.

Right now my .htaccess file is looking like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} opera
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} articleid=(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1000)

<If "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'articleid=001'">
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example.com/ [L,R=302]
</If>
<ElseIf "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'articleid=002'">
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example2.com/ [L,R=302]
</ElseIf>
<ElseIf "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'articleid=003'">
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example3.com/ [L,R=302]
</ElseIf>
<ElseIf "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'articleid=004'">
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example4.com/ [L,R=302]
</ElseIf>
etc...
```

Right now i get a 500 Internal Server Error error when it is entered like this. How to fix it to make it workable?

Best regrards,
salexes

Comment: Wha version of apache are you using?

Comment: apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 on centos 6.7
I just read that elseif etc. is just avaiable from 2.4. Is there a 2.4 apache version avaiable for centos 6.7 yet ?

Comment: If, elseif directives are available in Apache 2.4 and later,not in 2.2.

Comment: just curious, why don't you use PHP etc. to redirect such thing?

Comment: I just updated to 2.4 but i still get the error (Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server)

Comment: Check your Apache error.log and see what is causing 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing these rules to traditional mod_rewrite rule syntax and **keep redirects before default WP rule**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} opera
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)articleid=articleid=001(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example.com/? [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} opera
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)articleid=articleid=002(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example2.com/? [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} opera
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)articleid=articleid=003(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example3.com/? [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} opera
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)articleid=articleid=004(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example4.com/? [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```